# Oracle ORDS on Tomcat 8 hide schema name in url

Tags: oracle, tomcat8, oracle-ords

I don't want users being able to see the context or schema name in the ORDS URL.

As in the Oracle documentation my URL is something like this:

```
https://server:port/ords/workspace/hr/employees/7369
```

note the schema name, HR is present.  My goal is to hide ORDS, workspace and hr.  So my URL should be:

```
https://server:port/redirect_name/employees/7369
```

What I do not want is a HTTP 301 redirect which updates the browser bar.

**Things tried**

1) UrlRewriteFilter in ROOT but with type="redirect" it only redirects and leaks the context.  Without type="redirect" yields "The requested resource is not available." from Tomcat so apparently doesn't even get to ORDS.

2) JSP redirection

```
<% response.sendRedirect("/some/where"); %>
```

which successfully redirected, but leaks context.

3) Tomcat "rewrite Valve" again same result successful 301 type redirect.

**Not tried**

1)  Front Tomcat with an Apache httpd instance.

Comment: when you REST enable a schema, you are able to alias it, so that the db username isn't exposed via the URI - but you are expected to have SOMETHING on the /ords/ URI that denotes where to go get the REST definitions for db connection pool

Answer (score 3):

Answer applies to ORDS 3.0.9 only.  The [README](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/downloads/ords-readme-309-3415866.html) describes:

- BUG:25072243 - Fix regression preventing url mapping of ORDS enabled schemas iff the PL/SQL Gateway pool does not exist

without which I do not believe this will work (not tested).   Note if upgrade from ORDS 3.0.6 or earlier there have been changes to the DB schema and you need to upgrade.

This is not a full answer but it is the closest I managed to get.  First rename the ords.war file to the desired redirect_name.war  This will automatically create a new configuration directory for the database connection but will not yet be set up.  Options are to either install redirect_name.war using:

```
java -jar redirect_name.war install simple
```

or by manually editing the configuration files to match the ORDS settings you already have.  There are two ways to find the configuration directory either

```
java -jar redirect_name.war configdir
```

will give you the configuration directory or you can check it in:

```
.\webapps\redirect_name\WEB-INF\web.xml
```

with the param name  assuming Tomcat is configured to unpack WARs otherwise look in the compressed WAR archive itself.

At this point the URL has changed from this:

```
https://server:port/ords/workspace/hr/employees/7369
```

to this:

```
https://server:port/redirect_name/workspace/hr/employees/7369
```

The next step is to set up a map-url which can either be done using:

```
java -jar redirect_name.war mapurl --type base-path --workspace-id hr / apex
```

or by manually creating a url-mapping.xml file in the  found above.  If you manually create the file it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pool-config xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apex/pool-config">
   <pool name="apex" base-path="/" workspace-id="hr" updated="2017-01-01T01:01:01.012Z"/>
</pool-config>
```

The pool name "apex" is the default installed database name.  You can check which database names have been set up in ORDS by checking the /conf/ subdirectory where in a default install you will find a file named apex_pu.xml describing the database connection.  If you wish to connect to a different database [(more here)](https://smartdogservices.com/single-ords-install-multiple-databases/) that can be done with:

```
java -jar redirect_name.war setup --database ords_db_name
```

which will lead you through a series of prompts to enter either a service name or a SID.  Note that you must chose [1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/downloads/ords-readme-309-3415866.html) when prompted here:

```
Enter 1 if you want to verify/install Oracle REST Data Services schema or 2 to skip this step [1]
```

or the database connection won't be created.  To verify success check the /conf location and look for ords_db_name_pu.xml  Note that ords_db_name is just a database connection name alias used by ORDS it doesn't have to be an actual SID or service name.

These steps will bring the URL down from the intermediate step:

```
https://server:port/redirect_name/workspace/hr/employees/7369
```

to this:

```
https://server:port/redirect_name/workspace/employees/7369
```

the url-mapping.xml/mapurl option with / removed the need for any name.  Alternately this command could have been used:

```
java -jar redirect_name.war mapurl --type base-path --workspace-id hr /something_here apex
```

yielding this URL:

```
https://server:port/redirect_name/workspace/something_here/employees/7369
```

**Not tested**

Rename ords.war to ROOT.war in theory removes the need for "redirect_name" to be in the URL but I wasn't prepared to have ORDS in the ROOT location.